How to know if the secondary node is ok in MongoDb
I have a mongo replica set of 3 nodes. We use the primary for both write and read. Its a legacy system so it doesn't see much use. Mongo version used is 2.6.11 . When I run isMaster on one of the secondary nodes, this is the response I get.
{
    "setName" : "PROD DB",
    "setVersion" : 5,
    "ismaster" : false,
    "secondary" : false,
    "hosts" : [ 
        "xxxxxxxxxx:27017", 
        "xxxxxxxxxy:27017", 
        "xxxxxxxxz:27017"
    ],
    "primary" : "xxxxxxxxxx:27017",
    "me" : "xxxxxxxxxy:27017",
    "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
    "maxMessageSizeBytes" : 48000000,
    "maxWriteBatchSize" : 1000,
    "localTime" : ISODate("2024-08-01T04:10:16.843Z"),
    "maxWireVersion" : 2,
    "minWireVersion" : 0,
    "ok" : 1.0
}

Is the secondary working fine ? isMaster and secondary is both false.
Also the "rs.status()" result.
{
    "set" : "PROD DB",
    "date" : ISODate("2024-08-02T00:55:47.000Z"),
    "myState" : 3,
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "xxxy:27017",
            "health" : 1.0,
            "state" : 3,
            "stateStr" : "RECOVERING",
            "uptime" : 17607969,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1702118685, 6),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2023-12-09T10:44:45.000Z"),
            "infoMessage" : "still syncing, not yet to minValid optime 66aad5e1:60",
            "self" : true
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "xxxz:27017",
            "health" : 1.0,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 17607969,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1722560139, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2024-08-02T00:55:39.000Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2024-08-02T00:55:46.000Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2024-08-02T00:55:46.000Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "syncingTo" : "xxxx:27017"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "name" : "xxxx:27017",
            "health" : 1.0,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 17607969,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1722560139, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2024-08-02T00:55:39.000Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2024-08-02T00:55:46.000Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2024-08-02T00:55:46.000Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1702118698, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2023-12-09T10:44:58.000Z")
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0 }


You can connect to the replica-set  (from mongo shell) and then run the rs.status() (returns the status of the replica set) method. You can also edit and update your question post with the returned output document.

Done. Thank you

While rs.status() returns the status of a replica-set, you can use rs.config() (alias of rs.conf()) to get the configuration document for a replica set.

That looks like member _id:0 hasn't been replicating since last December.  Might be time for a resync
